# (QGIS desktop 3.2.) Selecting features (polygon) based on radius, using specific distance

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I'm a bit of a newbie in coding and geographical systems. At the moment writing my master thesis, so I need some information in terms of distances/neighbouring.

I'm currently working with Swedish data, so I'm using maps using the system: SWEREF 99 TM. I have a vector layer (points) which determine "locations of interest", and another vector (polygon) which divides the same map into districts. I want to select specific districts that are within a radius of the "location interest", say 1km, 2km, so on.

My problem is:

- How do I know I'm using the correct distances?
- Which tool should I use? I know I can select features by radius, but I can't find any option based on a specific radius.
- Is there also a way to select on the radius, but based on the centroids of the polygons?

Bellow a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) tool with the polygon layer as input and with this expression.

```
aggregate(
    'Point layer name', -- name / id of points layer
    'count',
    $id,
    distance(geometry(@parent), $geometry)  < 1000 -- set here de distance you want
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! From what I understand from the CRS information the measurement unit is in meters. I have tried your expression and it works! I'm just a bit puzzled about something, when I try to use the tool "distance to hub", on the same vectors, for some reason I always get an "nan" in the distance field. Any idea why?

Comment: Are the two layer in the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using EPGS:3006 SWEREF 99 TM for all layers

Comment: Make another post exposing this issue, maybe sharing some pictures and data.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? If it worked mark the answer as accepted, this help people with the same problem to find this answer easy.  

Comment: Hey it did! In the end I was able to find a solution for the Hub has well. I just Applied my projection to my project (again) and it somehow worked!